# Adding "Do Not Track" to iOS browser app with UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How would you enable/support "Do Not Track" for a browser app that uses UIWebView? Is this something that every app on iOS has to include by itself or is this already enabled in UIWebView?

Thanks!

Comment: See here.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track It's a browser preference that the major browsers have included recently to tell advertisers not to track them and send their personal info.

Answer (score 1):

Simple tools are coming like the one linked below -- add a line of JS at the top of the page and it turns off the tracking tags when the user has the DNT preference enabled. Should work on a mobile web view if you have a typical ad tag installation.

http://www.ensighten.com/news/blog/ensighten-privacydnt-free-tool-managing-compliance-do-not-track